# Adding GSONConvertorFactory to retrofit2 while calling an API

Tags: java, rest, gson, retrofit

I have many API's which I am calling from my application.
On response I have default `GsonConvertorFactory` which converts the JSON response to the corresponding Java objects with exact number and name of fields and everything works like a charm.
Below is the code:

```
 Retrofit retrofit = (new Retrofit.Builder()).baseUrl(baseUrl + serviceSuffix)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create())
                    .client(client)
                    .build();
            return retrofit.create(clientInterfaceClass);
```

The problem is when I had to do some changes for one API in which I have to modify the response before it gets mapped to the Java object and so i have written an adapter for it which is :

```
public class CaptureReceiptTypeAdapter extends TypeAdapter<CaptureReceipt> {

@Override
    public void write(JsonWriter jsonWriter, CaptureReceipt captureReceipt) throws IOException {
    }

@Override
    public CaptureReceipt read(JsonReader in) throws IOException {
in.beginObject();
        while (in.hasNext()) {
 String name = in.nextName();
  if (name.equals("receiptID")) {
                receiptID = in.nextLong();
            }  else if (name.equals("captor")) {
                captor = new CustomJIDAdapter().read(in);
            } else {
                in.skipValue(); // Skip any other fields
            }
}
}
```

and

```
public class CustomJIDAdapter  extends TypeAdapter<JID> {

//do some changes as required in json before mapping
}
```

Also now I am registering my Adaptors :

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                .registerTypeAdapter(CaptureReceipt.class, new CaptureReceiptTypeAdapter())
                .registerTypeAdapter(JID.class, new CustomJIDAdapter())
                .create();
    
Retrofit retrofit = (new Retrofit.Builder()).baseUrl(baseUrl + serviceSuffix)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                .addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create())
                .client(client)
                .build();
        return retrofit.create(clientInterfaceClass);
```

Now when I create a retrofit using 'gson', it does not work for rest of API's.
Is there any way we can switch between both the ConvertorFactory's, like it should switch based on type.

Comment: If only your `CaptureReceiptTypeAdapter` needs `CustomJIDAdapter`, then you don't have to call `registerTypeAdapter(JID.class, new CustomJIDAdapter())`. Is that what you meant? Or do you mean multiple of your APIs return `CaptureReceipt`, and only for one of them the custom adapter should be used. Also, is `CaptureReceipt` directly the return type of your API, or is there some enclosing class. In that case maybe [`@JsonAdapter`](https://javadoc.io/doc/com.google.code.gson/gson/latest/com.google.gson/com/google/gson/annotations/JsonAdapter.html) could be used for the `CaptureReceipt` field.